# There is any way to access headers of published event in masstransit saga?

Tags: c#, events, rabbitmq, masstransit, saga

Is there any way to access headers in saga when I published event like this ?

```
 await busControl.Publish<IOrderCreated>(new
        {
            OrderId = dto.Id
        }, context =>
        {
            context.Headers.Set(LogConstansts.Common.OperationId,Guid.Parse(values.Single()).ToString());
            context.Headers.Set(LogConstansts.QueueMessageHeaderNames.Publisher, Request.RequestUri.AbsoluteUri);
        });
```

and then in saga

```
Initially(
           When(OrderCreated)
            .Then(context =>
                  {
                    //get headers somehow?
                     context.Instance.OrderId = context.Data.OrderId; 
                  })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can access it by fetching the consume context payload from the behaviour context:

```
Initially(
    When(OrderCreated)
        .Then(context =>
        {
            ConsumeContext<IOrderCreated> c;
            if (context.TryGetPayload(out c))
            {
                c.Headers.Get<string>("myheader");
                // do something
            }
            context.Instance.OrderId = context.Data.OrderId; 
        })
```